# Python: Is there a way to systematically open files in a script until a directory has been exhausted?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, with-statement

I would like to write a script in Python that will systematically open files, but I'm not sure how that might happen. Essentially, I would like something like:

```
with open(file1) as thefile:
    #do stuff

with open(file2) as the file:
   #do the same thing as before

.... #does this until the directory is exhausted
```

There are a good number of files that this would need to happen for, so I'm looking for an alternative to hard-coding in a bunch of `with` commands. Is there a way to do this in a loop that will recognize that it has exhausted all the files in a directory?

Comment: [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)

Comment: Have you looked at os.listdir()?

Comment: You can use os.listdir to access all the files in a specific directory. Then you can use use a for loop to execute the same piece of code on all files returned by os.listdir

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many ways. One way is to iterate over the result of `glob.glob()`:

```
#UNTESTED
import glob
for filename in glob.glob('*'):
    with open(filename) as the_file:
        # do the thing
```

If you only wanted to operate on files with a particular naming pattern, you could use, for example: `glob.glob('ABC*.txt')`

Answer (score 0):

The Python **os** package has a lot of great tools for working with the operating system, especially file and process management.

```
import os

for f in os.listdir("."):
    with open(f) as the_file:
```